A conjectured generalization of Oppenheim's inequality, inspired by Horn-Yang's theorem
In this post, $A$ and $B$ are hermitian $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrices.
It is well known that if $A$ has rank $n$ and if $B$ has only positive entries on its diagonal, then the rank of the Hadamard product $A \circ B$ is $n$.
A quantitative refinement of the previous statement is Oppenheim's inequality, which states that if $A$ and $B$ are hermitian $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrices, then
$$ \det(A \circ B) \geq \det(A) \prod_{i = 1}^n b_{ii}. $$
In the article "Rank of a Hadamard product" by Horn and Yang, the authors show that if $A$ and $B$ are hermitian $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrices with no zero main diagonal entries, and if there is a $k$ in $\{1, \dots, n\}$ such that the rank of $A$ is greater than $n - k$ and all principal minors of $B$ are positive, then the rank of the Hadamard product $A \circ B$ is $n$.
I wonder if there is a quantitative refinement of the Horn-Yang theorem, which would thus also be a generalization of Oppenheim's inequality.
To make things interesting, I will actually write down a specific conjectured inequality. If $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, I conjecture, a bit as a wild guess, that
$$ \det(A \circ B) \geq \left(\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k-1}}\sum_{|I| = n + 1 - k} m_I(A) \prod_{i' \in I^c} a_{i'i'} \right) \left(\prod_{|J| = k} m_J(B)\right)^{\frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}}, $$
where $m_I(A)$ denotes the principal $n + 1 - k$ minor of $A$ with indices in $I$, and similarly for $m_J(B)$ (the principal $k$-minor of $B$ with indices in $J$), $I^c$ denotes the complement of $I$ in $\{1, \dots, n\}$.
It seems to have the properties we want, to have the right homogeneity and degree. Of course, this does not mean it is true. I am just throwing it out there as a possible conjecture, for fun. I did some numerical testing for $n = 3$, $4$ and $5$ as of now and could not find any counterexample yet.
Note that if $k = 1$, we recover Oppenheim's inequality.
